# See-through faces, but just in game and probably not because of normals?

Tags: 3d-view, faces, normals

I modelled and animated some low poly game characters with Blender and when I import them in Visual Studio MonoGame there are some parts of the modells see-through as you can see in the picture.
I read a lot about the normals for the faces and recalculating them or set them manually but it's not working for me. So please help.
Here are some pictures, sorry for the bad quality of the second.
[image]

[image]

As you can see the neck is see-through, but recalculating and manually flip the normals of the faces for the neck didn't helped.

Comment: From your first picture it looks like you have a hole in the neck area What is the big black spot?.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually my question, I managed to solve it.

The problem was, that there were some vertices, which haven't got any weight in the animation and therefore the game engine couldn't render their faces right.

I fixed it by editing more weight to this vertices.

The black area was the real face of the ape, for some reason you weren't able to see it even from backside.